# javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: No collection found

Tags: java, arrays, jsp

```
This is my arraylist for index 17
```

### In this code may have data list or may not. Data is dispay when there are records. Not handled for no records

**Java code:**

```
 //To avoid arrayindexoutofbound exception length checked
    if (resultList.length >17) {
    statisticsDetails.setqNames(resultList[17]);
    //System.out.println(resultList[17]);
    String[]  qName=resultList[17].split("\\^");


   List<StatisticsDetails> statisticsDetailsList = new ArrayList<StatisticsDetails>();
    for (String queueName:qName  ){
    StatisticsDetails  details = new StatisticsDetails();
    String[] splitQueues = queueName.split("=");
    details.setqKey(splitQueues[0]);
    details.setqCount(splitQueues[1]);
    statisticsDetailsList.add(details);
    }
    statisticsDetails.setqNamesList(statisticsDetailsList);
    }
```

**Jsp  code:**

```
<logic:iterate id="iteratorId" name="statistics.statisticsDetails" property="qNamesList">
<tr>
<td class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6"><bean:write name="iteratorId" property="qKey" /></td>
<td class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6"><bean:write name="iteratorId" property="qCount" /></td>
</tr>
</logic:iterate>
```

how to avoid arraybound error and JSP to handle  when no data found

Answer (score 1):

1. Use a null check using JSTL`(Do not forget to import the tag library)`:
    import core library:
   `<%@ taglib prefix = "c" uri = "http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>`
   and then use:

   `<c:if test="${not empty statistics.statisticsDetails}">
           //keep your code here to iterate the list
    </c:if>`
2. Or use:

   `<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" prefix="fn" %>`
   and then:

   `<c:if test="${fn:length(statistics.statisticsDetails) > 0}">
     //keep your code here to iterate the list
   </c:if>`

Answer (score 0):

Please check all mapping is correct or not in the struts-config.xml. In my case, i found incorrect type was mentioned for form and then it was giving the error. Type means package name for the form. in  tag.